# Javascript regex - reusing patterns to capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm just trying to learn javascript regex and have been stuck on [this problem](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions/reuse-patterns-using-capture-groups) for a while.

I need to match patterns, some examples below:

```
console.log("42 42 42 42".match(reRegex)); // should NOT match
console.log("42 42".match(reRegex)); // should NOT match
console.log("42 42 42".match(reRegex)); // should match
```

I have tried a lot of versions of this, but can't figure it out. Can you tell me how this works?

This is incorrect as it matches `42 42 42 42`, which it shouldn't.

```
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /(\d+)(\s)\1\2\1/; // Change this line
let result = reRegex.test(repeatNum);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have alook at [anchors](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#:%7E:text=Anchors%20belong%20to%20the%20family,the%20end%20of%20a%20line.)

Add a $ if it is per line: `/^(\d+)(\s)\1\2\1$/`

https://regex101.com/r/FFwPWF/1

Comment: Same answer, just too slow :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `^` at the beginning and add `$` at the end of your regex.

https://regex101.com/r/7EUpOb/2

Regex101 is a good reference and has good explanation during execution of regex!

Comment: No problem, happy to help ;) @william3031

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible Solution

```js
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /^(\d{2,3})(\s)\1\2\1$/; // Change this line
let result = reRegex.test(repeatNum);
```

It was matching also `42 42 42 42` so you have to limit the regex by adding string anchors at the beginning and end of the regex

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(\d{2,3})[ ]\1[ ]\1$/

\d{2,3} - should match only 2-3 digit number.
[ ] - Only space character
\1 - captured group 1
^ - beginning of the line.
$ - end of the line
```

Tested this expression in the link you gave and it passes all tests.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions/reuse-patterns-using-capture-groups